# LazyInitializationException in Spring with JPA entity

Tags: java, spring

I want to switch from EAGER to LAZY fetching on my JPA entity, but then I get an error. I have tried a lot of solutions and been searching for a while now for a solution that works - can't find anything that works on Google... And I don't want the entity to join fetch either.

Error: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: package.User.wallets, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Webcontroller file:

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @GetMapping("app/")
    public ModelAndView app() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("app/index");

        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        List<Wallet> wallets = user.getWallets(); // error on this line
        mv.addObject("wallets", wallets);

        return mv;
    }
}
```

User files:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    // FetchType.EAGER solves the error, but I can't have EAGER due to performance issues.
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Wallet> wallets;

    // ** getters and setters **

}

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

}
```

Wallet files:

```
@Entity
public class Wallet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="currency_id", nullable=false)
    private Currency currency;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double balance;

    // ** getters and setters **

}

@Repository
public interface WalletRepo extends JpaRepository<Wallet, UUID> {

    Optional<Wallet> findByUserAndCurrency(User user, Currency currency);

}
```

Thanks for reading all this, I would really appreciate any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by that the User object in SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
had already closed the connection even though @Transaction was annotated in Controller class.

I had to change the Controller class like this:

```
    @GetMapping("app/")
    public ModelAndView app() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("app/index");

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        User user = userRepo.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername()).orElse(null);

        List<Wallet> wallets = user.getWallets(); // no error anymore
        mv.addObject("wallets", wallets);

        return mv;
    }
```

Hope this can help anyone else, because I couldn't find this mistake anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**The origin of your problem:**

By default hibernate lazily loads the collections (relationships) which means whenver you use the collection in your code the hibernate gets that from database, now the problem is that you are getting the collection in your controller (where the JPA session is closed).This is the line of code that causes the exception (where you are loading the comments collection) :

```
List<Wallet> wallets = user.getWallets();
```

**Solution**

you have this on your User entity

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Wallet> wallets;
```

use this

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Wallet> wallets;
```

> Collections are lazy-loaded by default

**UPDATED Solution**

This particular case will be solved by adding toString() in `User` to re-define over Lombok toString()

keep your `fetchType.LAZY` instead `fetchType.EAGER` and 
add toString method to your User Entity

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", email=" + email+ ", firstName=" + firstName+ ", lastName=" + lastName + ", password=" + password+ "]";
    }
```

and add to you Wallet Entity :

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
  private User user;
```

try to add `@Transactional` to your controller too

Comment: That would solve the problem by changing back to FetchType.EAGER, but that causes the performance n+1 issue that I want to avoid. The code I shared is simplified to fit in a post, but I really can't have FetchType.EAGER that would overwhelm the application.

Comment: See Updated answer !!

Comment: you have to try my solution and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` above your `AppController` class and then lazy loading will work.

Example:

```java
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Controller
@Transactional
public class AppController {

    @GetMapping("app/")
    public ModelAndView app() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("app/index");

        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        List<Wallet> wallets = user.getWallets(); // error on this line
        mv.addObject("wallets", wallets);

        return mv;
    }
}
```

If it didn't work, you probably don't have enabled transaction management (this is normally configured by Spring Boot auto configuration). Try to add `@EnableTransactionManagement` e.g. above the main application class, where `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is used.

You could also try that line below:

```java
Hibernate.initialize(user.getWallets());
```

Comment: I wish that would solve the problem, but it didn't and that's so weird..